# Using Visual Source Safe 2005 in Stand alone Aptana

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, aptana, visual-sourcesafe-plugin, visual-sourcesafe-2005

How can we use Visual Source Safe plug-in in standalone Aptana installment. People say one can only use that plug-in in eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install Eclipse to get this to work.  I have not seen an Aptana Plugin for standalone installations.

Comment: im not sure what you're asking.  but you can install aptana as a plugin for eclipse which will give you what you are looking for.  If you dont wish to install eclipse then as of right now there is no way to get VSS to work with a standalone installation of aptana

Comment: Ok then, Thanks,it seems it's not gonna work with standalone aptana anyway.